# ng-model throwing error on input type number in angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an input field which I want he user to input a number, so I have made an input field with type="number".

When I use it in 1.2 I get no errors

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.person = [
            {"name": "Alex","pts": "10"}
        ];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        {{person | json }}<br>
        name: <span ng-bind="person[0].name"></span></br>
        <!-- pts: <input ng-model="person[0].pts"> -->
        pts: <input type="number" ng-model="person[0].pts"><br?
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPKgVL

However when I use it in 1.3 I get  Error: [ngModel:numfmt] but when i update the number it still seems to get bound to the scope.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.person = [
            {"name": "Alex","pts": "10"}
        ];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        {{person | json }}<br>
        name: <span ng-bind="person[0].name">
        name: <span ng-bind="person[0].name"></span></br>
        <!-- pts: <input ng-model="person[0].pts"> -->
        pts: <input type="number" ng-model="person[0].pts">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPvJro

Am I doing something wrong here or is this nothing to worry about?  I would prefer not to have the errors in my console, when I am trying to debug other issues

Comment: The short answer is that it expects the number `10`, but your model gives it the string `"10"`. In the future, use non-minified Angular (remove .min) to see more elaborate error messages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to number or date in angularjs expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657130/how-to-convert-string-to-number-or-date-in-angularjs-expression)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58581897/4816207

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define the `pts` property as a `number` instead of a `string`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.person = [
        {"name": "Alex","pts": 10}
    ];
}]);
```

Answer (score 19):

Add this to fix the issue:

```
myApp.directive('input', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (
                   'undefined' !== typeof attrs.type
                && 'number' === attrs.type
                && ngModel
            ) {
                ngModel.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                    return Number(modelValue);
                });

                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                    return Number(viewValue);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This is handy if you don't have complete control over your JSON model (for example, mine also had to support strings in that property so changing it to an integer type wouldn't work for me).

Answer (score 8):

This directive will parse the string value for any input of type 'number'. Then you will get no errors:

```
module.directive('input', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
            if(attrs.type == 'number'){
                ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value){
                    return parseFloat(value);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes around "10". Angular is expecting a number, and you're giving it a string.

Answer (score 2):

Is Easy solution Error "AngularJS Documentation for numfmt" parse Type in Int Or Float ;-)

```
<input type="number" ng-model="inputNumDemo" />

....
    app.controller('Demo',[ '$scope', function($scope){

      // Input numeric convert String "10" to Int 10 or Float
      $scope.f.inputNumDemo = parseInt(d.data.inputDemo );

    }]);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just add this code in app.js

```
angular.module('numfmt-error-module', [])

.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.typeOf = function(value) {
    return typeof value;
  };
})

.directive('stringToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return '' + value;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```